# injecting javascript to FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'd like to create a handle through which I would be able to inject javascript to Firefox.

I can do it very easily with IE but Firefox is a different story...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [grease monkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).

Comment: it's really unclear that this is what the OP is looking for given that he mentions he's doing this in IE ok

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do exactly:

- insert JS in your own browser manually?
- insert JS in your browser automatically for some websites?
- insert JS in somebody else browser when they visit your website?

Maybe you can describe how you do it with IE. Once we know what you are trying to achieve, we'll probably be able to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it in a manual way, using Firebug extension.

1. Console.
2. Find a small triangle on the right that's "Command editor", press it.
3. Paste the code.
4. Run

The code:

```
var b = document.createElement("div");
b.innerHTML = "<button onclick='jarektest();'>text</button>";
document.body.appendChild(b);

// short code typed inline
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.innerHTML = "function jarektest() { alert(document.body.innerHTML); }";
document.body.appendChild(s);

// longer piece, taken from other file
var s2 = document.createElement("script");
s2.src = "file:///J:/lang/js/hello.js";
document.body.appendChild(s2);
```